# Maine coon kitten biting

Tags: cats, biting, maine-coon

Plz " Coverback " the one who asked this question on 2013 
[At what age cats should stop biting and scratching games](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1834/at-what-age-cats-should-stop-biting-and-scratching-games)

If you see this question help with your experience  and answer
All other fellows also welcomed

Hi I have exactly the same situation with a 3 month maine coon ( got him when he was 1 month old) and he keep biting whenever he is close to my hand or feet, wondering what you did with your kitten and how it behave now?

Comment: Please consider commenting in that question. Or use chat.

Comment: If there's no reply in that question then post a new question